# Markov Inequality in graph theory

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Fix an optimal solution G∗ to k-Cycle-Free Subgraph. Partition the vertex set V of G randomly into two subsets, A and B, each of size n/2, and remove edges internal to A or B. In expectation, the fraction of edges in G∗ that remain after this process is 1/2. ***With probability at least 2/3 the fraction of edges in G∗ that remain is at least 1/4; here we apply the Markov inequality on the fraction of edges inside A and B***.

I know Markov inequality in context of probability theory I don't know what it means here.

[APPROXIMATING SUBGRAPHS WITHOUT SHORT CYCLES](https://www.openu.ac.il/home/mikel/papers/cycles-APPROX08.pdf)

Comment: It is the same Markov inequality that you know.

Comment: This appears to be copy-pasted from the paper [Approximating Maximum Subgraphs Without Short Cycles](http://www.academia.edu/download/30602401/Ashish_Goel_Approximation_Randomization_and_Com.pdf#page=128), without attribution.  We require that you provide [proper attribution to the sources of your material](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).  Providing attribution helps you identify your sources, protects you, and helps provide context that might help other answer your questions more effectively.  Please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: When you add a reference, note that we expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. We have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a purely mathematical question with no computational content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the fraction of remaining edges. We know that $0 \leq X \leq 1$ and $\mathbb{E}[X] = 1/2$. Let us define $Y = 1 - X$, which is the fraction of edges inside $A$ and $B$. This is a non-negative random variable whose expectation is $\mathbb{E}[Y] = 1/2$. According to Markov's inequality,
$$
\Pr[X < 1/4] = \Pr[Y > 3/4] = \Pr[Y > \tfrac{3}{2} \mathbb{E}[Y]] < \frac{2}{3}.
$$
Therefore $\Pr[X \geq 1/4] > 1/3$.

Let us show that the similar inequality $\Pr[X > 1/4] \geq 1/3$ is tight, that is, there exists a random variable satisfying $0 \leq X \leq 1$, $\mathbb{E}[X] = 1/2$, and $\Pr[X > 1/4] = 1/3$. Indeed, take $\Pr[X = 1/4] = 2/3$ and $\Pr[X = 1] = 1/3$, and notice that
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
In a similar way, one can show that $\Pr[X \geq 1/4]$ can be arbitrarily close to $1/3$.